# Will iOS apps created in Yosemite/Xcode 7.1.1 still work on iOS 10 (iPhone7)?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

XCode 7.1.1 seems to be the max version available for OS X Yosemite.

In the Wiki page, iOS 9 seems to be the SDK included.

Will apps created and built with XCode 7.1.1 still work on iOS 10? Is there some sort of default/fallback/generic system that allows IPhone 7 to use apps built year or two ago or on older version of XCode?

Comment: No, Xcode 8 can be installed on OS X Yosemite 10.11.6 version.

Comment: Not according to this it can't https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#7.x_series of course, this info could be incorrect. XCode 7.1.1 came back with the max when I researched it as some other parts SDK etc aren't compatible with Yosemite. Could be wrong though, this is my first Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps will be work. But, if you send on review new version - you need build apps with new SDK(in this case on XCode 8+).

UPD:
In comments people say, that you can build app with iOS SDK 9+ using Xcode 7.

Comment: Where has Apple stated that you need to use Xcode 8?
I've just submitted an App build with the Xcode 7 and the iOS 9 SDK it was reviewed just fine.

Comment: Apple hasn't was wondering whether IPhone 7(iOS 10) would still work with apps built on older versions of Xcode. (that have no mention or reference to iOS10)